# Взаимодействие Си функции и Lua

Tags: c++, c, lua

Если мы вызываем функцию си из луа, результат затем попадает в некую статическую функцию на которую мы ссылаемся (создает локальный стек).

Как из этой функции можно извлечь значения, скажем, для некоего класса или переменной?

Comment: Было бы намного нагляднее, если бы вы сопроводили свои слова кодом.